# How to call NavigationController within class, not derived from UIViewController?

Tags: ios, xamarin

My service class hasn't derived from *UIViewController*, but I'd like to call *NavigationController* to move to another controller.

```
class AppoxeeService
{
    public void ShowInbox(){
        ..
        //this code doesn't work (of course), 
        //because class isn't derived from UIViewController
        NavigationController.PushViewController(new AppoxeeInboxController(), true)

        //this code is mostly possible,
        //but the NavigationController is null here
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(new AppoxeeInboxController(), true)
    }
}
```

The Xamarin documentation is described well only for storyboards, but I'd like  dynamically find current *RootViewController* and bind it to *NavigationController*.

In other simple (aka "HelloWord") samples from Xamarin or their documentation it is possible to instantiate from *FinishLaunching* method:

```
        var window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds) {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.White
        };

        rootViewController = new RootViewController ();
        navigationViewController = new UINavigationController (rootViewController);

        window.RootViewController = navigationViewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
```

I'm fully stucked with *NavigationController* and its usage from code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write complex code.
just call your instance of Navigation Controller that you declared in  AppDelegate class

*In AppDelegate.h*

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

*In AppDelegate.m*

```
@synthesize navigationController
```

then your code in didLaunch Method

in your class

just call the instance anywhere

[(((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work in Xamarin. I tried to create separate *UINavigationController*, but it should be bounded to *RootNavigationController*, else it didn't had sense. (